# What utility creates a ".migoDesktop" in my user directory?

Tags: windows, user-directory

I have a HP Mini 110 running Window 7 Starter, from which I uninstalled all the utilities they installed in the netbook; still, every time I switch it on, and log in on my account, the ".migoDesktop" directory appears in the user directory, even if I delete it.

The directory contains the following files:

- MigoDesktopReslet.FavBookmarks.dat
- MigoDesktopReslet.FavFolder.dat
- MigoDesktopReslet.Pwd.dat
- MigoPreferences2

What utility creates the directory? How do I uninstall it?

The programs that the applet to uninstall programs shows are the following ones:

[image: screenshot]

The processes that runs on my netbook are the following ones:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Windows is localized in Italian; *SERVIZIO DI RETE* means "network service," and *SERVIZIO LOCALE* means "local service."

Comment: If they provided a Windows install disk, I recommend you reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its Migo Desktop Sync
http://www.migosoftware.com/kingston/migosyncbundle/

its a syncing software for multiple devices
It should be removable through the windows control panel

Comment: I don't see that application listed in the programs I can uninstall. I would be happy if I could stop the program starting when I start the computer.

Comment: one thing you can try is to find it in the task manager, and kill it. then find the install directory with the search and just delete it. Then next time the computer starts it wont run. Also another thing is to play with the startup options in 'msconfig'

Comment: I did also that, but I didn't find any suspicious program, even choosing "show the processes for all the users."